# Installing R package "validate" exits with error

Tags: r, azure

I'm trying to install the package validate using `install.package("validate")`, but I get the following error message:

```
Installing package into ‘C:/Users/xxx/Documents/R/win-library/3.6’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)

  There is a binary version available but the source version is later:
         binary source needs_compilation
validate  0.9.3  1.0.1              TRUE

installing the source package ‘validate’

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/validate_1.0.1.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 1990096 bytes (1.9 MB)
downloaded 1.9 MB

* installing *source* package 'validate' ...
** package 'validate' successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** using staged installation
** libs

*** arch - i386
C:/Program Files/R-Tools/mingw_32/bin/gcc  -I"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-3.6.1/include" -DNDEBUG          -O3 -Wall  -std=gnu99 -mtune=generic -c R_fdep.c -o R_fdep.o
sh: C:/Program: No such file or directory
make: *** [C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-3.6.1/etc/i386/Makeconf:208: R_fdep.o] Error 127
ERROR: compilation failed for package 'validate'
* removing 'C:/Users/xxx/Documents/R/win-library/3.6/validate'
* restoring previous 'C:/Users/xxx/Documents/R/win-library/3.6/validate'
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘validate’ had non-zero exit status

The downloaded source packages are in
    ‘C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Local\Temp\2\Rtmp08xXa8\downloaded_packages’
```

I've tried installing the package on my local machine and there I have no issues. This issues occurs when I try installing the package on a Azure-Cloud. Other packages install fine however. Also when I install the package using the "binary" option, it works fine... That is, howeverm, not the most recent version and there are some functionallities we want to use from the newest version.

Has anyone else encountered this problem and has a solution?

Comment: if you are installing from source (and there is code to compile) on Windows you need to have rtools installed; https://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/Rtools/. Or else just install the binary

Comment: The Binary is not the newes version

Comment: @user20650 we are facing this issue for some weeks now. as you can see in the error message, the binary is version 0.9.3 and the source is 1.0.1... Also R-Tools is installed on the Azure-Cloud

Comment: fyi https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/validate/index.html seems to list the windows binary as v1.0.1

Comment: ah i just noticed you have R v 3.6.1. This is two year old and sometimes this can cause an issue

Comment: @user20650 I see the correct version in the link you provided, I can't download the .ZIP-File due to company-policies... is there a way to download/install the specific version directly via R-Studio?

Comment: @user20650 Ok, I was able to download the binary and the it worked. If you would like to make you comment about the R-Studio version an answer, I would like to mark it as such... I have found, that several people where searching for an answer, maybe this will help in the future.

Comment: please go ahead and write up an answer as you know best what worked for you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the Help of user20650 I was able to find a solution.

We have an older version of R and R-Studio installed on our Cloud. This causes issues when installing packages with `install.packages`. Apparently only the newest source-file, but not the newest binary is considered. To overcome this I needed to download the binary manualy from [cran](http://cran.r-project.org). Then I installed the binary in R-Studio using Tools -> Install Packages... -> Install from: Package Archive file -> select Binary